# Cauchy's Theorem, Deformation Theorem, similarities and differences - Complex Variable

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

1) Let $f$ have an antiderivative $F$ in a region $D$ containing a $\underline{closed \,\,\,contour}$ $C$. Then
\begin{equation}
\int_Cf(z)dz = 0
\end{equation}

2) Also, Cauchy's theorem says: If f is $\underline{holomorphic}$ inside and on a $\underline{closed \,\,\,contour}$ $C$ then
\begin{equation}
\int_Cf(z)dz = 0
\end{equation}

Then why is Cauchy's theorem so important and what is the difference between this one and the previous one? It looks to me that the previous one required less conditions than this.

3) Finally, another theorem is:
If f is $\underline{holomorphic}$ on a region $D$ and $C_1$, $C_2$ are $\underline{closed \,\,\,contours}$ in $D$, which can be continuously deformed into each other within $D$, then:
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_1}f(z)dz = \int_{C_2}f(z)dz
\end{equation}
Is it now obvious? Of course they are, they are zero!

4) Deformation Theorem:
Let $f$ be $\underline{holomorphic}$ in a simply connected region $D$. Then:
\begin{equation}
\int_Cf(z)dz = 0 
\end{equation}
for every closed contour $C$ in $D$.

Where simply connected means: that any closed contour in $D$ can be continously deformed within $D$ to a point.

Again, is this not saying the same thing as above??
I really don't get the difference between all these theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(2) Holomorphic means simply that $\exists f'$. Why $\exists F$ s.t. $F' = f$ is "less"? Even more, what condition is easier to check?

(3) In this case, interesting things can happen *out* of the region. Check what happens to $f(z) = 1/z$ in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$. And the integrals can be $\ne 0$!

(4) is a consequence of (3).

Comment: So between (1) and (2) the difference is that for (2) we can differentiate the function at every point, while for (1) we can integrate it at every point? And I thought it was less because you don't have to know anything about the derivative. To be honest differentiation is easier, so it makes sense

Comment: For (3) there is the same example in my book but I don't understand. We say that it works IF it is holomorphic on D. Which means differentiable at all points in D. Clearly $f(z) = 1/z$ is not differentiable at $z=0$, so we shouldn't consider it. Or should we? And also, you say outside of the region. Why should we care? The contours we are integrating on, they are inside the region!

Comment: @Euler_Salter, take a path *around* 0.

Comment: oh okay! So basically (3) is saying that now we don't consider the function holomorphic inside and on the contour. We only consider it holomorphic in the region, however we substitute that condition with the ability of continuously deforming any two contours inside the region?  Does it mean that being able to continuously deforming two contours in a region, means the region itself has no gaps/holes or points in which is not defined?

Comment: @Euler_Salter, exactly. *Simply connected*.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla  f is holomorphic Holomorphic by definition doesn't say that $\exists F$ such that $F'=f$. Holomorphic simply means that the complex differentiation exists. To prove that holomorphic implies anti-derivative, that is your $F$ exists is a long process. First one shows that holomorphic implies integration over any triangle is zero, then one deduce integration over any rectangle is also zero. using these two result one can prove holomorphic implies anti-derivative exists and hence we deduce Cauchy's Theorem: Holomorphic implies integration over any closed curve is zero,

Comment: @Babai, selfquote: ''Holomorphic means simply that $\exists f'$". The OP is saying that existence of primitive is "less" than holomorphy.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla  Looking at the question OP has possed, for him obviously having antiderivative and holomorphicity is are two different concepts. Look at his bulleted first and second point.

Comment: @Babai, quote form the OP: "It looks to me that the previous one required **less** conditions than this."